# C: How to access certain cell in array defined via typedef struct?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

C: How to access certain cell in array defined via typedef struct?

```
typedef struct array {
    char field[4][4];
} Test;

Test array = {
    .field = {
        {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},
        {'1', '2', '3', '4'},
    },
};
```

How to go get access for example to character `'C'`?

`array.field[0][3]` doesn't work.  `array.field[0]` will return 0. and 1. column of array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With CodeBlocks , I test that and it's work
char C= array.field[0][2]
Full code:

```
typedef struct array {
    char field[4][4];
} Test;


int main()
{
Test array = {
    .field = {
        {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},
        {'1', '2', '3', '4'},
    },
};
    printf("value -- %c\n",array.field[0][2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first element of array is 0th element, so try `array.field[0][2]`.

Answer (score 0):

this works in VS 2012:

```
Test array = {{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', '1', '2', '3', '4'}};
char c = array.field[0][2];
char four = array.field[1][3];
```